# Which browsers block 3rd party cookies by default?

Tags: security, cookies, browser

I want to have a feeling which percentage of our traffic does not support third party cookies. For this I need to now Which browsers / OS combinations currently block 3rd party cookies by default. Does anybody know?

Answer (score 3):

Currently, in mid-2018, the following browsers block third party cookies by default:

- Safari
- Firefox

As far as I can tell, no other browsers block third party cookies by default otherwise, although all browsers offer an easy option to enable it.

Also to be considered: Many AdBlockers and other extensions in browsers block third party cookies, like Adblock Plus, uBlock Origin, uMatrix, and many more. You can therefore assume quite a lot of people will block them, and they will only increase over time, as more people use ad and tracking blockers - and maybe more browsers will block third party cookies by default in the future.

It depends a lot on the country you are interested in to determine percentage-wise the number of people who block third party cookies. In some countries it easily exceeds 50%.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any data regarding that last statement?

Comment: For example, in Switzerland the usage of Safari is at about 40%, the usage of Firefox is about 11%, and the usage of adblockers are between 8-18%. So it is clearly above 50%, maybe even 60 or 70%. In other countries the usage of Safari is a lot lower, yet Firefox may be higher (for example Germany), so these percentages can vary.

Comment: As an addition my own statistics for an online shop in Switzerland: Safari usage is at 33%, Firefox is at 15%, so already 48% are always blocking third party cookies. Add in some people using adblockers or who changed the third party cookie settings or installed an extension to do it for them, and you have at least 50%.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has an option to disable 3rd party cookies. It could be configured as default policy, if needed.
Chrome will also show a red warning on the address bar if some cookies are blocked so that the user can understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Safari blocks 3rd party cookies if the 3rd-party site that is trying to set a cookie was not visited by user.
Firefox blocks only tracking cookies by default, and enabling block all cookies is an option like in other browsers: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/disable-third-party-cookies.
Chrome, IE and Edge do not block 3rd-party cookies by default: https://clearcode.cc/blog/browsers-first-third-party-cookies/